# Create column of start date and end date from given date record

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date

supposed my dataset

```
Name date
A    15-01-01
A    15-01-31
A    16-02-02
A    16-03-04
B    17-04-05
B    17-05-08
B    17-07-09
C    18-01-02
C    18-02-03
```

I want to add each person's first and last dates to a new column..

result what I want

```
Name date     startdate enddate
A    15-01-01 15-01-01  16-03-04
A    15-01-31 15-01-01  16-03-04
A    16-02-02 15-01-01  16-03-04
A    16-03-04 15-01-01  16-03-04
B    17-04-05 17-04-05  17-07-09
B    17-05-08 17-04-05  17-07-09
B    17-07-09 17-04-05  17-07-09
C    18-01-02 18-01-02  18-02-03
C    18-02-03 18-01-02  18-02-03
```

Is there a method to make this possible? I would appreciate it if you let me know.

thank you for reading

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with [`GroupBy.first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html) or [`GroupBy.last`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.last.html) and add to new columns:

```
g = df.groupby('Name')['date']
df = df.assign(startdate = g.transform('first'), enddate = g.transform('last'))
print (df)
  Name      date startdate   enddate
0    A  15-01-01  15-01-01  16-03-04
1    A  15-01-31  15-01-01  16-03-04
2    A  16-02-02  15-01-01  16-03-04
3    A  16-03-04  15-01-01  16-03-04
4    B  17-04-05  17-04-05  17-07-09
5    B  17-05-08  17-04-05  17-07-09
6    B  17-07-09  17-04-05  17-07-09
7    C  18-01-02  18-01-02  18-02-03
8    C  18-02-03  18-01-02  18-02-03
```

Or if need minimal and maximal with [`GroupBy.min`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.min.html) and [`GroupBy.max`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.max.html):

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%y-%m-%d')
g = df.groupby('Name')['date']
df = df.assign(startdate = g.transform('min'), enddate = g.transform('max'))
print (df)
  Name       date  startdate    enddate
0    A 2015-01-01 2015-01-01 2016-03-04
1    A 2015-01-31 2015-01-01 2016-03-04
2    A 2016-02-02 2015-01-01 2016-03-04
3    A 2016-03-04 2015-01-01 2016-03-04
4    B 2017-04-05 2017-04-05 2017-07-09
5    B 2017-05-08 2017-04-05 2017-07-09
6    B 2017-07-09 2017-04-05 2017-07-09
7    C 2018-01-02 2018-01-02 2018-02-03
8    C 2018-02-03 2018-01-02 2018-02-03
```

Alternative with [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) with [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
df1 = df.groupby('Name').agg(startdate = ('date','first'), lastdate = ('date','last'))
df = df.join(df1, on='Name')
```

Comment: I'm still in my walking stage, I'm still lacking my googling skills.. In your answer, I experience the new world every day and feel that there is a long way to go. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to do it. While I am not very sure but it should work.

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%y-%m-%d')
start_date =[]
end_date = []
first_ittr = True;
index = 0

for i in df['date']:
    if(first_ittr):
        start_date[index] = i
        end_date[index]=i
        first_ittr = False

    elif(i>end_date):
        end_date[index] = i

    elif(i<start_date):
        start_date[index] = i

df['startdate'] = start_date
df['enddate'] = end_date
```